# Is there a way to change the PayPal IPN callback url at a later date?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've searched the developer documentation and cannot find anything.
This feature would be good so I can code a website in plain php then recode it from scratch at a later date.
Can I use a 301 Redirect?

Comment: That's what _sandbox_ is for and in any (other) case, [it is documented](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/)...

Comment: I looked at that page and it doesn't tell me how to change the callback url. i am using PayPal Payments Standard and it says that the HTML form decides the callback url. But the HTML form is only used to initialise a recurring payment, so it cannot change the callback url. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the notify_url variable in your button to specify "The URL to which PayPal posts information about the payment, in the form of Instant Payment Notification messages."

For more information visit the following link:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Comment: You haven't answered my question. I don't want to know how to set the notify_url. I want to know how to change it from what it was set previously, at a later date.

Comment: You can then forget about the notify_url parameter in your button and define the IPN listener at your PayPal profile (seller preferences -> instant payment notification). That way you can, at later date, change the IPN listener to a different URL. Agree?

more info here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/

Comment: But I want to define the callback url in the HTML form, not the Paypal website.

Comment: Then the answer is "no".